# NoHttpResponseException after changing GET request to POST

Tags: java

I was calling the GET API using RestTemplate.
However, due to the query lenth issue of the API, I requested the API provider to change it to POST.

NoHttpResponseException occasionally occurs after changing to POST.

The API provider supports both GET / POST.
I don't know why NoHttpResponseException occurs only on POST requests.

I know that NoHttpResponseException is caused by CLOSE_WAIT.
Is this  NoHttpResponseException related to GET -> POST request change?

The errors that occur are as follows.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I / O error on POST request for "XXXX": XXXX failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: XXXX failed to respond
```

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute (RestTemplate.java:732)

Thank you.

Comment: Could be a problem on the side of the API provider. For some specific request you send, the implementation throws an exception but instead of cleanly reporting the problem to the caller, it the request just dies and does not give any response at all -> thus resulting in the NoHttpResponseException on your side. If you can reproduce the problem, you should contact the API provider about it.

Comment: Have you specify SSL configuration for your RestTemplate?